# "Um tipo de dados é um conceito abstrato definido por um conjunto de propriedades lógicas." - O que isso significa?

Tags: tipagem, estrutura-de-dados, ciência-da-computação

Estou lendo o livro "[Data Structures Using C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131997467)", e uma das coisas que o livro explica é que um conjunto de bits não possui nenhum significado intrínseco, e que o significado de um dado conjunto de bits é dado a este conjunto a partir da maneira como ele é interpretado, assim sendo o mesmo conjunto de bits pode ser interpretado como números inteiros, números de ponto flutuante, ou caracteres. Pelo menos foi isso que entendi.

Mais a frente o livro explica que ao declarar uma variável em uma linguagem como C, por exemplo, o tipo daquela variável é utilizado pelo compilador para instruir a máquina sobre como interpretar os bits armazenados no endereço de memória alocado por aquela variável.

O que me confundiu é quando o autor afirma que podemos ver o conceito de "tipos de dados" de uma maneira diferente, não em termos de o que o computador pode fazer, mas do que o usuário quer que seja feito, e que uma vez que o conceito de tipo de dados seja distanciado das capacidades do hardware os tipos de dados que podem ser considerados são ilimitados.

É onde então é feita a afirmação "Um tipo de dados é um conceito abstrato definido por um conjunto de propriedades lógicas".

Qual o significado desta afirmação? Até o momento não consegui absorver este conceito.

Logo em após esta parte segue-se: "Once such an abstract data type is defined and the legal operations involving that type are specified, we may implement that data type (or a close approximation to it)".

Comment: Qual afirmação vc se refere a 1º ou a 2º ?

Comment: @MagicHat A primeira.

Answer (score 1):

Ele quer dizer que um tipo de dados é definido pelas regras que definimos a ele durante sua implementação.

É uma estrutura com regras pré-definida - na implementação - referente a qual dado pode ser armazenado nela ou não.